# How to recompile a decompiled swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, compilation, flash

I decompiled a swf file to customize it.

I used this site http://www.showmycode.com/ which gave me some code:

```
package {

    import mx.core.*;
    import mx.events.*;
    import flash.geom.*;

//...

public class LoadSchedule extends Player {

    //...
```

How can I recompile this code to turn it back into SWF?

Comment: thats action script not java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out it is action scritp and i can use the eclipse fdt plugin to compile back the code as swf
http://fdt.powerflasher.com/docs/Basic_AS3_Tutorial#Source_Files
this works.
Or this too :http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/Adobe_Flex#Installing_the_free_Flex_SDK

Comment: Hi! how about i use adobe flash pro/cc? i tried the adobe flash/cc to recompile the decompile swf(add some actionscript), then generated swf is different and it's size is smaller than the original.